Stick particles to a surface accurately on the face upon hit on a deforming and/or moving mesh using simulation nodes?
Using Simulation nodes, I have particles spawning and moving in a certain direction and are supposed to stick to a mesh
Currently my approach is to sample the UV Coordinate on the nearest surface upon hit, and use that later to sample it back to 3D using Sample UV Surface node or this method

Here I sampled the UV coords to the points that hit and set their positions to that UV space for demonstration purposes
But I'm stuck figuring out how to keep the sampled UV coordinates once it hits as the mesh moves/deforms which is important to keep the particle stick
I am aware that 3D Singh VFX already made the same effect but I don't have $10 in my pocket right now and I'm in Blender 3.6 so there's no Repeat zones
If this isn't the best method or it's just impossible, let me know your solution
Nodes and Blend file

